# Software solution for duplicating files to multiple USB flash drives simultaneously

Tags: usb, imaging, flash

We are distributing data to hundreds of customers using USB flash drives.

There are expensive hardware solutions to duplicate USB flash drives.

Is there any cheap software alternative using a regular PC connecting many USB drives using USB hubs.

We would like to write at least 10 USB drives at a time.

Comment: Good question- just write a script! Isn't it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [ImageUSB](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html) looks like it does what you're looking for... and it's free. :)